# Could not find a declaration file for module 'is_js'

Tags: typescript

I have two Typescript projects. I have these dependencies in the package.json of both:

```
"dependencies": {
   "is_js": "^0.9.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "@types/is": "0.0.21",
},
```

Both tsconfig.json-s contain

```
  "strict": true
```

And I have this line of TypeScript code in both:

```
import * as IsJS from 'is_js';
```

In one of the projects, I get a compiler error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'is_js'. '/Volumes/Me/Project/node_modules/is_js/is.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/is_js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'is_js';`

The other project compiles fine and I can also see the typing information of IsJS object in VSCode hover tooltips. Please help me figure out what might have gone wrong with this project.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the cause of this, but at least I've found a workaround. Write this line at the top of the file that imports IsJS:

```
/// <reference types="is_js" />
```

This makes the type declarations available in that file even though they weren't found automatically.